# Do I need to call VariantClear after VariantChangeType

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, variant

I have the following code in C++. Do I need to free 'varDest' variable?

```
VARIANT val;
if(SUCCEEDED(classObj->Get(pwPropName, 0, &val, NULL, 0)))  //WMI property retrieval
{
    //Then at some point
    VARIANT varDest;
    varDest.vt = VT_EMPTY;
    if(SUCCEEDED(::VariantChangeType(&varDest, 
        const_cast<VARIANT *>(&val), 0, VT_BSTR)))
    {
        //Do I need to call the following?
        VariantClear(&varDest);
    }

    VariantClear(&val);
}
```

Comment: @Mahesh COM has special memory management rules which are independent of `new / delete`

Comment: @JaredPar I amn't aware of COM programming. Sorry, will delete my comment :)

Comment: Because of this common misconception about COM that Mahesh just expressed, Windows is so full of memory leaks. I wish MSDN was better at explaining this...

Comment: @Mahesh then you should probably abstain from posting COM suggestions.

Comment: @ahmd0 Anything that is `C++` drags my interest. Since I amn't aware of COM, I gave it as comment. Or else I would have made it as an answer and earned few downvotes :) Had if I hadn't made this comment, I wouldn't have **not** known the fact that memory management for COM is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you must call `VariantClear`.  The `VariantChangeType` method if successful will essentially coerce a copy of the source into the destination.  This copy in the destination is now independently tracked and must be independently cleared.